# Creating a function that accepts input of name and outputs all the names with the same cluster label as the input name

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, user-input, user-defined-functions

`

```
eval_players = pd.read_csv(r"file_location")

bld = eval_players ['buildup']
att = eval_players ['attack']
bld_att = np.column_stack((bld,att))
km_res = KMeans(n_clusters = 3).fit(bld_att)
cluster = km_res.cluster_centers_

plt.scatter(bld,att)
for k,row in eval_players.iterrows(): 
     plt.text(row['buildup'],row['attack'],row['Name'])
plt.scatter (cluster[:,0],cluster[:,1], s = 500)

   clust = km_res.labels_
eval_players['cluster'] = clust.tolist()`
```

Ive already done the clustering and added the cluster label as a new column in the dataframe. So now i just need a function that takes the name as input checks their cluster label and returns all the names with that label.

I am very unfamiliar with creating functions, I only started coding seriously a couple months ago, so if anyone can help me out that'd be great. Also if there's already an inbuilt function that can do this please let me know.

I tried the input function but the next few lines of code are way above my level of understanding of python.

Comment: please provide more information about what a cluster is and how are you accessing the names and clusters? what data structures are you using? and by input, do you mean a user input or a function argument? It would be better if you provide the code for these question

Comment: @NavidNaseri added the code i have so far. I meant user input like with the input() function